# How can i print variable value defined in the method of a different class in python?

Tags: python, class, methods

```
class ClassA:
    def __init__(self):

        def val1(self):
            a = 1
            b = 2
            return b

class ClassB (ClassA):
    def val2(self):
        print(b) # b has been defined in ClassA var1 method
```

Comment: There are many many possible answers to this.  Voting to close as too broad

Comment: Is b a member of ClassA? If so you may declare it as such.
If not you could call val1 method from ClassB with 'self.val1'

Comment: why would you that anyway? one option is to use global variables

Comment: @DejanMarić. That's not a good option at all.

Comment: can you explain why?

Comment: @DejanMarić. Because it defeats the purpose of encapsulating into a class in the first place, for one thing.

Comment: Is the indentation of `val1` correct? Is it really defined within `__init__`?

Answer (score 1):

The following answer is predicated on the assumption that your indentation is wrong and that `val1` is a method of `ClassA`, not a nested function in `ClassA.__init__`. In the latter case, since the function is not returned anywhere, there is absolutely nothing you can do, so I will disregard that possibility.

To get the value, you have to call the method which returns it. You can not access the local variables within a method outside it. Those variables only exist for the duration of a call anyway, and get recreated every time:

```
def val2(self):
    print(self.val1())
```

Or more verbosely:

```
def val2(self):
    b = self.val1()
    print(b)
```

An alternative is to make the value non-local to begin with, and use it as a regular attribute:

```
class ClassA:
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = 0

    def val1(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 2

class ClassB (ClassA):
    def val2(self):
        print(self.b) # prints 0 until `self.val1` is called.
```

Comment: Wouldn't the temporary function variables "defined" in `def val1` be inaccessible anyway?

Comment: @usr2564301. I hope my update addresses the issue. I only just now noticed the indentation problem. If OP's indentation is correct, then yes, the situation is hopeless without further modification. However, the presence of `self` in the argument list leads me to allow for the possibility of slopiness rather than deliberation here.

Comment: is it possible to access the value of b in val1 method in classA from val2 method in classB ? understanding this will help me finish the project i'm currently working on.

Comment: @AkparevaInnocent. I believe that my answer is pretty complete. Could you clarify what is confusing you at this point? If be happy to expand.